# How to create an XML file from user input query?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a c# windows form application that queries Oracle. I already have the function to export results to XML from a query stored inside the application. I also have a textbox on the form for a user to input a custom query. I was wondering how I can create an XML file from the custom query result without knowing the fields in advance. I cannot post my code for the public, but I can give more detail where needed.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on "user input query" and "create an XML file" from the results. [You can build dynamic XML with ease](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387087.aspx), so I'm not sure where your problem lies (and likely will not without adequate code or background).

Comment: @user1546889 Surely its possible to come up with a generic reduction of your code that doesn't give away secrets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store your query results into a C# `DataSet` object you and call `DataSet.GetXml()` and it returns an XML representation of your dataset.

Comment: Thank you. I am storing the information in a DataTable and I got WriteXML to give me the output I was looking for. Your suggestion lead me in the right direction.